# Error from FormatNumber function when non-number is inserted

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm using the following piece of ampscript:

```
FormatNumber(@BillAmount,'F0','en-US')
```

Occasionally, a non-numeric piece of data is added to the @BillAmount (assumption, not 100% sure yet). When this happens, the the whole journey stops due to the following error:

```
ExactTarget.OMM.FunctionExecutionException: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a FormatNumber function call. The input value () cannot be formatted as a number. The first parameter value for a FormatNumber call must be a numeric type supported by the requested format.
Value: 
Format: F0
Error Code: OMM_FUNC_EXEC_ERROR@
- from OMMCommon
```

Assuming I can't fix the bad data coming in, is there a way I can structure the ampscript to skip this if the data isn't numeric? Trying to fix this so the whole journey doesn't conk out in this edge case.

Any advice?

Answer (score 2):

You could also do it inline:

```
%%=iif(empty(@billAmount),'0.00', FormatNumber(@BillAmount,'F0','en-US'))=%%
```

Reference:

- [**iif()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/iif)
- [**empty()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/empty)
- [**formatNumber()**](https://ampscript.guide/book/formatNumber)

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It was due an empty value. I excluded those with with an if statement. Not elegant, but it seems to have worked.

```
%%[if NOT EMPTY(@BillAmount) then]%%
```